# jquery function to change the some html of a specific tr when all tr share the same class

Tags: php, jquery, html

So i have this table with multiple tr that has the same class, lets call this class "same" now the table is dynamic meaning i can add multiple tr with same class. now inside the tr is a select tag that onchange will call the function type_switch, now type_switch will then append some html content on that tr depending on the selected option so the change should only happen on that specific tr not on all, now the problem is that at first everything was A-ok but when i decided to transfer the place where the html content should be added on a tr inside the tr everything stopped working. for more info here is the code for type_switch:

```
function type_switch(elem,act_id){
var tr = $(elem).parent('td').parent('tr');
// var tr = ".actionrow";
var appendum = "";
if(act_id!=undefined)
appendum = "&action_id="+act_id;

$(tr).children('.type-label').html("<img src='<?php echo BASE_URL;?>admin/images/ajaxloader.gif' />");
$(tr).children('.type-selection').html("<img src='<?php echo BASE_URL;?>admin/images/ajaxloader.gif' />");


$.ajax({
url: "<?php echo BASE_URL;?>somewhere.php", data: "type="+$(elem).val()+"&method=get_type_criterions"+appendum, type: "POST", dataType: "json",
success: function(d){
if(d.error==0){
$(tr).children('.type-label').html(d.label);
$(tr).children('.type-selection').html(d.cont);
$(tr).children('.type-button').html(d.btn);
}
}
});
}
```

a sample of the tr that can be added repeatedly:

```
<tr class="action-row">
<td valign="top">hello&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="top"><select name="crm_action[[id]]">
<option value="add">Add to Group</option>
<option value="transfer">Transfer to Group</option>
</select>
</td>
<td valign="top">Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
<td valign="top">
<select name="funnel_type[[id]]" class="funnel-type" onchange="type_switch(this[,id])">
<?php
$sql_tg = "some select";
$res_tg = mysql_query($sql_tg);
while($tg = mysql_fetch_object($res_tg)){
$sql_t = "some select";
$res_t = mysql_query($sql_t);
if(mysql_numrows($res_t)>0){
echo "<optgroup label=\"{$tg->label}\">";
while($t = mysql_fetch_object($res_t)){
echo "<option value=\"".$t->id."\">".$t->funnel_type_label."</option>";
}
echo "</optgroup>";
}
}
?>
</select>
</td>
<td><img src="<?php echo BASE_URL?>admin/images/action_delete.png" title="Delete" onclick="delete_row(this)" style="cursor: pointer;" /></td>
  //this is the part that i changed there should be no tr holding this 3 td but since the layout looks ugly and messy i decided to transfer it below.
      <tr class="actionrow">
  <td class="type-label" valign="top">[label]</td>
      <td class="type-selection" valign="top">[selection]</td>
  <td class="type-button" valign="top" align="right" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</tr>
```

Generated HTML code:

```
  <tr class="action-row">
 <td valign="top">CRM Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
      <td valign="top"><select name="crm_action[]">
 <option value="add">Add to Group</option>
 <option value="transfer">Transfer to Group</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 <td valign="top">
 <select name="funnel_type[]" class="funnel-type" onchange="type_switch(this)">
 options to determine what to display in this tr onchange
 </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 <img src="somewhere/action_delete.png" title="Delete" onclick="delete_row(this)"     style="cursor: pointer;"></td>
 </tr>
 //this part should have been inside the above tr as you can see it the php code above
 <tr class="actionrow odd">
 <td class="type-label" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-selection" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-button" valign="top" align="right" colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
 //end              
 <tr class="action-row">
 <td valign="top">CRM Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 <td valign="top">
 <select name="crm_action[]"><option value="add">Add to Group</option>
 <option value="transfer">Transfer to Group</option>
 </select>
 </td>
 <td valign="top">Action:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
 <td valign="top">
 <select name="funnel_type[]" class="funnel-type" onchange="type_switch(this)">
 another options
 </select>
 </td>
 <td>
 <img src="somewhere/action_delete.png" title="Delete" onclick="delete_row(this)"      style="cursor: pointer;">
 </td>
      </tr>
 <tr class="actionrow odd">
 <td class="type-label" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-selection" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-button" valign="top" align="right" colspan="2"></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: please post the generated HTML instead of PHP+HTML

Comment: Have you tried to .append() instead of replacing with .html()?  If I read correctly, you're over writing something in your TR which then makes it not work.  Try to append() (or prepend.() if you want it before).  This will add whatever code you want, instead of replacing it

Comment: @ntgCleaner  how will i make it so that it will only append on the current tr? since all share the same class i wont have any identifier, and im not that familiar with the parent child relationship too. thank you

Comment: You would use the $(this) selector.  For example, if you have a button inside of a tr, it would be $(this).parent().append()  This makes it so when you click the button ($(this)) it will find it's parent, then you append the information you would like

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example of what you might need:

```
$('.select').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().append(*your html here*)
});
```

This will append the information inside the tr, instead of the select box.

I believe this is what you're asking, if not, I will change my answer to your comment.

EDIT to OP request:
To be able to change the specific elements inside of the tr, you can use those specific classes with .children(), .find() and .closest().  Here's an example:

```
$('.funnel-type').change(function(){
    var thisTr = $(this).parent().parent();
    thisTr.children('.type-label').html("something here");
    thisTr.children('.type-selection').html("something here");
    thisTr.children('.type-button').html("something here");
})
```

Basically, I have made a variable to make it easier to use the select box's parent TR (thisTr).  Then, if each  is a child of the main tr, we just specify each one by it's own class, then do whatever we want to them.

Comment: i tried using this but it change the values for all the tr. thank you

Comment: I'm not sure how that's possible.  $(this) handles that particular select box.  Strange.  Does it change ALL trs or all trs in that particular group?

Comment: it changes for all with tr class = "action-row".

Comment: That's very strange.  Can you please add your code to a fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/ and recreate what's hapenning?

Comment: it works in the jsfiddle but on my site it only works on the first tr not on the second, also what i want html to append to is on class actionrow how is that possible? here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rrgS4/

Comment: @ntgCleaer yes but i want to it to target the children of class actionrow

Comment: Ok, so you would just add another .parent() to go up one more level.  http://jsfiddle.net/rrgS4/3/  If I am missing something here, please let me know.  I just know you would like to append data to it's parent's parent, but the html looks like you want to be able to append data to the first or second tr depending on which option you select.

Comment: would you mind explaining the answer a bit more, also how will i be able to specifically change the html of <td class="type-label" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-selection" valign="top"></td>
 <td class="type-button" valign="top" align="right" colspan="2"></td>.. thank you

Comment: I have added a bit of an explanation.  If you would like more, please let me know.